# How to control applications using VPN

Tags: windows-10, vpn, comodo-firewall

I use Windows 10, I use Comodo firewall.
I have restricted some apps from using internet.
when the VPN service is turned on, or some VPN software like Hotspot shiled is turned on, the blocked apps can use internet!
How can I restrict them?
THank you.

Comment: What Comodo product are you using?

Comment: comodo internet security premium 10, the version 8 was the same.